# Getting OOPS when trying to install Rhel 7.8 on dell laptop

Tags: redhat, dell, rhel7, laptop

I've upgraded a `Dell Inspiron 15` to 32GB RAM, so I could use Red Hat on it.
However, when I try to boot from a USB that contains `rhel 7.8 DVD ISO`, I get the following OOPS:

[image: OOPS]

**Can rhel 7 be installed on this Dell laptop?**

*Notes*

- for my development needs (clients), I have to use rhel 7.
- CentOS 7.6 also gives an OOPS when I try installation from a USB (which I installed several desktops from).

Comment: This is a second (or subsequent) crash message from the same session. Can you get the original message? It should have relevant details; this does not. Try booting with the `inst.text` command line option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Michael. Unfortunately, I reinstalled the laptop in text mode, which worked. All I had to do after the installation was to tell rhel to start in graphic mode.